How do I get Excel to remove a reference to one of my VBA projects?
I have a VBA project with a number of functions I want to use in other projects, which let's say I decided to name helpfulFunctions (via the project's properties window). Oops, I accidentally named a different project helpfulFunctions, and didn't realize it until I had already added helpfulFunctions as a reference in another project (via the Tools>References menu option).
I removed the reference, saved, then renamed the second project to something else, saved it, and then tried to name the intended project helpfulFunctions, but now Excel says the name is taken by another module/project/library. I've tried removing the mistakenly named project in the manage add-ins option dialog and re-launching Excel, but still it complains. I tried removing the file containing the project, and still Excel complains. How do I remove it properly?
